# Power BI, 365 authentication pass through

Tags: azure, authentication, powerbi, office365

Quick question. We have all of our users set up in Azure 365 for outlook.

We use those same users to provide access to power BI via a pro license.

I have embedded some reports onto a web page and was hoping given that all of our users will already be logged in to outlook 365 that it would not prompt them for login on these web pages but BI does.

Am I wrong in thinking that power BI should detect the user is already logged in via outlook and not ask again?

Answer (score 0):

I think if your users are already authenticated through Azure Active Directoryfor other Microsoft 365 services like Outlook, and you embed Power BI reports in a web page, the authentication should be seamless, and users shouldn't be prompted for login again.

here is the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Configure%20Single%20Sign-On%20for%20Power%20BI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=CORS%20Configuration

Comment: That was my thought, but isn't the case for me certainly, I wonder if there is some setting to allow Auth to be shared

Comment: Hi again, yes there are settings and configurations to enable shared authentication, especially in the context of  (SSO) with Azure AD and Power BI. check azure documentation for detailed info, I will attach the link in answer.